# return global object from function

Tags: r, function

I know `<<-` can be used to assign local variable to have global scope, however I want to understand the reverse whether its possible to access global variable inside function, an example below to illustrate what I mean. Any way to do this in R without reassigning it inside function as a global variable

***Expected output***: `z is a global variable`

```
z = "z is a global variable."

z_function = function(){
   z <- "z is a local variable"
  return(z)
}

z_function()
```

Comment: The `<<-` assignment doesn't necessarily assign with global scope.  If the function was defined somewhere other than the global environment, it can assign there.

Answer (score 1):

R has a "search path" if there is no scoped variable of the same name, the global environment will be searched for the symbol. Because you are assigning a scoped variable within your function with the same name as the global variable the function will return the local variable as it is found in the search path first. Functions order their own `{ scope }` higher in the search path

```
z <- "Global"
z_fun <- function() z

> z_fun()
[1] Global

z_fun2 <- function() {z <- "Scoped"; return(z)} 
> z_fun2() 
[1] "Scoped"
```

Comment: It's a bit more accurate to say "if there is no scoped variable of the same name, the environment where the function was defined will be searched".  Functions in packages see package definitions first, functions defined in other functions see variables in the enclosing function first.  And if the variable is not found there, the search continues to the parent of that environment, eventually all the way back to the base environment.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know if I understand your question correctly, but if **R** does not find a variable inside the function it will look in the environment and "search" the variable name.

So the following code gives "z is a global variable"

```
z <- "z is a global variable."

z_function = function(){
   ## z <- "z is a local variable"
  return(z)
}

z_function()
```

Comment: There is no way to explicitly invoke global variable something like global::z ? I thought there was a way, hence the question.

Comment: There is, you can use `.GlobalEnv$z` to be explicit.